# UTF-8 problems when sending 'git format-patch' files with mutt

Tags: git, mutt

Yesterday I created a commit in git, used `git format-patch` to create a patch and finally sent this patch as an email via mutt, using `mutt -H <patch>`. Somewhere along this chain my name, that contains an 'ö', got messed up. I need to find out where it got messed up and how to fix it.

This is my commit using `git show <commit>` (with some changes for privacy):

```
commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Author: Name Sandström <my@email.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 26 21:41:08 2017 +0100

    [...]
```

Output of the file produced by `git format-patch HEAD^`:

```
From xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: =?UTF-8?q?Name=20Sandstr=C3=B6m?= <my@email.com>
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2017 21:41:08 +0100
Subject: <commit subject>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

After executing `mutt -H <patch>` and entering to and subject, mutt opens vim with this:

```
From: =?UTF-8?q?Name=20Sandstr=C3=B6m?= <my@email.com>
To: <to address>
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Subject: <subject>
Reply-To: 

[...]
```

If I send this email to someone that uses e.g. Gmail, my name will show as `=?UTF-8?q?Name=20Sandstr=C3=B6m?=` in the web ui, and not `Name Sandström` which I expect.

I've tried both with having the mutt option `send_charset` unset and with having it set to `us-ascii:utf-8`, but the name still looks like above. The only difference I see is that the raw email contains `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1` when having `send_charset` unset and `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` when having `send_charset` set to `us-ascii:utf-8`.

How do I solve this? Who is doing something wrong here? git, mutt, Gmail or me?

**Edit**: I'm using:

```
Mutt 1.5.23
git version 2.11.0
```

**Edit**: It seems as if mutt is doing something wrong. mutt 1.7.1 seems to successfully decode my name.